# KendoUi format broken after require.js optimize

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, kendo-ui, requirejs, r.js

I have a Backbone application with multiple KendoUi components e.g. Grid, NumericTextBox. To display this value *"12,5 h"* in a numericTextBox I use this format:

```
this.$('.kendoHourInput').kendoNumericTextBox({ 
    format: '#.0 h'
});
```

For the development Version (not optimized), everything works as expected. For the production Version, after the require.js-optimizer, this format breaks the app:

```
Uncaught Bad number format specifier: #
```

The predefined formats like "c2" or "p" works without a problem. Could it be a problem with the kendo.culture('de-DE') I use? I had similar problems with the library *globalize.js*, which overrides the kendo.culture. Is there a known dependency to another library who could break the optimized-code?

> UPDATE

I found the library which caused the error: **globalize.js** There is a 2nd library with dependencies to globalize.js:

**require.js-config**

```
shim: {
    ...
    someLib: {
        deps: ['globalize']
    }
}
```

There is a [forum entry](http://www.telerik.com/forums/issue-datepicker-popup-doesn-t-work-if-jquery-globalize-was-included-before-kendo-ui) on the kendo site, with a similar problem. The solution should be to load the kendo library before the globalize library. If I take a look to the script-tags on the index.html, kendo comes before globalize. So, this is not a solution that works for me.

> UPDATE
>   Just use the newer version of globalize.js to get it work. I use version 1.0.0-alpha.3 of globalize.js now and everything works. There is a good [how to](https://github.com/jquery/globalize). Keep in mind that kendo should be loaded after globalize.js. **The order changed**

For more information, please let me know.

Thanks

Sascha